# Destroy Multiple Records With Model Binding Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have this problem to destroy multiple recors with model binding,
I have in **RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
  parent::boot($router);
  $router->model("offices","App\Office");
}
```

**The Destroy Method is:** (I'm returning $id just to check):

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   //Office::destroy($id);
   return $id;
}
```

My Url is sending

```
<form id="delete_offices" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost/public/offices/18,19" method="POST"><input type="hidden" value="DELETE" name="_method">
<input type="hidden" value="CXnq068rEYlu88gemilBZKh6f4ZL5p7cELmZoe4B" name="_token">
<button type="submit" id="btn_delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

But when I see what is returning in my controller, only return one object:

```
{"id":18,"name":"Main",,"phone":"9784773366","email":"","schedule":"Monday-friday: 8am-6pm","country_id":147,"state_id":476,"city_id":1178,"created_at":"2016-05-08 17:22:04","updated_at":"2016-05-08 17:24:57"}
```

What can I do to have the object with all info?, if I send ids 18 and 19 , I should get the 2 offices, the office info with id 18 and the info with id 19. If I send id 23 I should get only the info of the office with id=23.

Thanks

Comment: its okay if he answers his question i think if he found the solution later ! thats why its available in the first place!

Comment: Achraf, it's stackoverflow, it's not Facebook or quora and etc. There are lot's of questions with answers, there are professionals that want to help. Let's say he found answer, so why not deleted his question? Who is interested in his solution? - Only him. If You're pro, try to not support those who tries to garbage SO. Also read rules of stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to override any Route from Route::resource you should add this to your resource

```
Route::resource('office', 'OfficeController',
                ['except' => 'destroy']);
```

and then just add the route manualy

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution.
First I had the Route

```
Route::resource('office',OfficeController');
```

So this make all the REST routes like GET,POST,PUT,PATCH AND DELETE
All with the Wildcard {office},
So for example

```
Route::get('office/{office}/edit','OfficeController@edit');
Route::delete('office/{office}', 'OfficeController@destroy);
```

All routes has the same wildcard.
So because in the routeServiceProvider  I have:

```
$router->model("offices","App\Office");
```

I had to rewrite the routes one by one and the DELETE ROUTE

```
Route::delete('office/{office}', 'OfficeController@destroy);
```

Change it for:

```
Route::delete('office/{id}', 'OfficeController@destroy);
```

That way I get  the ids I send, not the Office Model.

If you know how to override any `Route` from `Route::resource`, it will be better and avoid writing each route